# docker container is not able to reach out to my localhost

Tags: node.js, docker, npm-start

I have installed docker toolbox recently and created a new container called "superawesomecontainer2" for training porpuses and every time I run this container I have to re-install my package.json and if I used -p 3001:3001 so I can run my server at localhost it's just not working and whenever I shut down this container and re-run it, I have to reinstall my package.json and then it won't reach to my localhost ?

some shits I have tried to solve this problem
-remove my package-look.json inside that container
-clean cash --force
-re-install my packages 
-re-installing docker it self

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "facerecognitionapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "clarifai": "^2.8.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "knex": "^0.15.1",
    "pg": "^7.4.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5"
  }
}
```

my docker file

```
FROM node:10.16.0

WORKDIR C:\Users\C.M\Desktop\smart-barin-api

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

docker info

```
E:\javascript\facerecognitionapi>docker info
Containers: 38
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 38
Images: 51
Server Version: 18.09.6
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: bb71b10fd8f58240ca47fbb579b9d1028eea7c84
runc version: 2b18fe1d885ee5083ef9f0838fee39b62d653e30
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.14.116-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 18.09.6 (TCL 8.2.1)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 989.4MiB
Name: default
ID: LRFB:QJNW:CCDA:2Y7X:XZWB:FREX:O4JB:D7PN:KWDK:ACPH:B6FC:Y4KY
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

expect: my server runs at localhost 3001
I don't re-install my packages every time I run this container

Comment: what do you mean by activating this container and how you do that

Comment: I have edited it I meant run it``` docker run -it superawesomecontainer2 ```

Comment: you havent exposed port 3001 in your docker file

Comment: Also when you run  it never installs automatically packages, so there must be something else you are missing here to share

Comment: and please update this comment, its not clear what you meant

Comment: -remove my package-look.json inside that container -clean cash --force -re-install my packages -re-installing docker it self

Comment: I tried it using 
docker run -it -p 3001:3001 superawesomecontainer2

Comment: @GaneshKarewad , with this line I put everything I have tried before writing this post

Comment: how your server starts, your command is ["bin/bash"] which will not start a server, and workdir looks wrong

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems in your `Dockerfile`.

- `WORKDIR`: refers to the directory structure **inside** the container. So it should not contain a Windows like path but something like `WORKDIR /app`.
- `COPY`: since you copy all the file in the current folder to the destination folder, you must include at least **in the same folder as the `DockerFile`**: `index.js` and `package.json`.
- `EXPOSE`: you have to expose the port of your server running in the container, this is done through the `EXPOSE` directive. For example `EXPOSE 8000`. Then you have to map the port when running the container `-p 8000:8000`. Change the port according to your needs or your configuration.
- `CMD`: contains the command that will be executed at the start of the container. If it contains `/bin/bash` it will execute a shell and just exit if you do not run it in interactive mode. So you have to start something like `CMD ["npm", "start"]`

In conclusion your `Dockerfile` should more look like this.

```
FROM node:10.16.0
# create and go to the app dir
WORKDIR /app
# copy all local file to the app dir
COPY ./ ./
# install the app
RUN ["npm", "install"]
# tell docker what port to expose
EXPOSE 8000
# start the server
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And you should build and run it like this:

```
$ docker build -t mynodeapp:latest .
$ docker run -p 8000:8000 mynodeapp:latest

# ...
# Server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

If you can also check an example [here](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/).

Comment: yea, it worked locally but it stills not connecting to my localhost,

Comment: I mean that I can't reach my server from the front-end or even using postman